# ssh and screen automatically - what am I missing?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

This works fine, but does not load my `~/.bash_profile` on server2. Why?

```
$ ssh -A -t server1 ssh -A -t server2 bash -c "screen -dR"
```

Comment: I won't answer on your question, but I may recommend you an alternative - `byobu` is a user-friendly interface above screen&tmux. To realize possibility to run it automatically, you may simply run `byobu-enable`, and it will run every time after logging.

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` `man` page:

```
When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash
reads  and  executes  commands  from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if
these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the  --norc  option.
The  --rcfile  file option will force bash to read and execute commands
from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.
```

You either reattach to an existing session within the running `screen` (maybe with an already running `bash`),
which doesn't require a login shell. Or you create a new `screen` session with a new, interactive non-login shell. Only login shells process `.bash_profile`.

The `bash` you specify on the commandline that start the `screen` command, is a different invocation altogether.